# Work on Springs using Hooke's Law

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, mathematical-physics

I'm currently stuck on parts c and d of this problem. The problem says Suppose a force of 20 N is required to stretch and hold a spring 0.4 m from its equilibrium position (0). I found k constant to be 50 and part b required using integration on 0 to -0.3 for spring compression on the and I found the work to be 2.25 J. Here's part c and d...

c) does it take twice as much work to compress the spring 0.6 meters from equilibrium as it does to compress 0.3 meters from equilibrium?

d)Does it take twice as much force to compress the spring 0.6 meters from equilibrium as it does to compress 0.3 meters from equilibrium?

I'm assuming you just solve the work for 0.6 compression and compare it to 2.25 J for c but im not sure about d. Please let know your thoughts and ways to approach this.

Comment: When doing the integration for 0 to -0.6 I get 9 J and then divided by 2.25 J I get 4. I'm assuming its more than twice as much work its actually 4 times as much work. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** From [Hooke's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)
$$
F=kx
$$
we can derive the formula for [spring potential energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law#Spring_energy) by integrating with respect to position
$$
E=\frac12kx^2
$$

Comment: what do i use the spring potential for?

Comment: I assume you are taking a course in physics and studying [force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force) and [work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29). If so, you know that work performed on a system adds to the sum of its kinetic energy and its potential energy. Compressing a spring will add to the potential energy of the spring. The spring was presumably not moving before the force was applied and has stopped moving while the force is being applied. Thus, there is no change in kinetic energy, so the work has gone into increasing the potential energy.

Answer (score -1):

For any future people who'd like to know the answer to this question.

For c) you can just calculate the work for compressing the spring 0.6 meters and compare it to the work for 0.3.

And for d) all you have to do is plug in -0.3 and -0.6 and compare the result. Hooke's law assumes a linear spring ( F(x) = kx ) which is an odd function so stretching or compressing x amount either direction takes the same amount of force and since F(x) = kx doubling or tripling the x-value will do the same to the result, as shown below.

F(x)  = kx

F(2x) = k(2x) = 2kx

or

F(-x) = -kx

F(-2x) = k(-2x) = -2kx